# Running regressions on short panel data with most dependent values being zero

Tags: regression, python, panel-data

I have student loan data and am trying to predict the amount that a particular `deal_name` (which has several loans associated with it) will prepay for a given month. The equation is:  $$log(Prepay Amount_{it}) = \alpha_1  \mathrm{Int rate_{it}} + \alpha_2 \mathrm{Hasdefaulted_{it}}$$

The data, as seen below has some idiosyncrasies to it:

1. There are a lot of rows for which `Sum_ppy_amount` is 0. As per the answer [here](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Which-is-the-best-regression-for-a-logged-dependent-variable-that-contains-many-zeros) I'm considering using a two-part model. The *first part* would be a logit that gives the probability of a person prepaying, and the *second part* would give the actual dollar amount. I can then estimate prepay amounts by multiplying the probability of prepaying times the predicted value of prepaying.
2. The panel data appears to be in a wide/short format per the definition [here](https://www.stata.com/meeting/wcsug07/cameronwcsug.pdf) i.e. There are many `deal_name`s (~20000) with respect to the number of observations/`Date`s associated with each `deal_name` (~20) so the panel data is short. Correspondingly, Fixed Effects and Random Effects models would not be appropriate.

My question is two fold, given that I have described the data correctly in 2. (that is, that the data is correctly defined as short/wide), does it make sense to do the following-

1. For the *first part* of the model: Run a Gaussian [GEE](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.genmod.generalized_estimating_equations.GEE.html) as prescribed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50784406/panel-probit-in-python) for short/wide panel data **on all of the data available** and then use the sigmoid function to convert the predictions into a probability?
2. For the *second part* of the model: Run a Gaussian GEE on only the data for which `Sum_ppy_amount` is not 0?

```
        Date          deal_name   int_rate             \
0     01/01/19        SKY          4.6-5.0         
1     02/01/19        SKY          4.6-5.0       
2     02/01/19        TMP          4.1-4.5      
3     02/01/19        TMP          4.1-4.5           

  has_def     Sum_ppy_amount   
0    0           141,904.57         
1    1           141,657.98   
2    1           142,357.18   
3    0           133,137.11
```